# Can't connect to MySQL replica on Google Cloud SQL unless it's is promoted to master

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql, database-replication, database-administration

I'm using Google Cloud SQL and I have a master MySQL 5.7 server with a working replica. I can't downsize the storage of the replica so I want to create a new replica, test it, and after everything's working I eventually will turn off the original replica and stay only with the new replica and the master.

So, I created the new replica and once it's available I changed 2 configurations: "allow unsecure connections" and I also I opened the public IP to 0.0.0.0/0. Then, I try to connect with the same user and password as the master/original replica but I get `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '{{my_user}}'@'{{my local ip}} (using password: YES)`. I double checked my user and password and they are correct.

Curiously, if I promote the new replica to master then the connection works!

I'm creating this new replica in the same way I created the original replica, so I don't know what could be different this time. I also checked every configuration I can think of, but haven't found anything yet. I even tried 2 different MySQL clients (the CLI for Linux and Heidi SQL for Win). I tried to update the password on the master and even created a new user, still no luck. I don't have any anonymous user in the master and all users (except mysql.sys) are available to all hosts ("%").

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After many retries I found out that restarting the replica fixes the problem. At present I suspect this is a bug, just not sure if MySQL's or Google Cloud SQL's.